# Redirect any non-existent pages to its existent parent

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How to make www.example.com/blog/postname/anything-non-existent be redirected to www.example.com/blog/postname. I've tried a .htaccess trick with no success.

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/blog/(.*) [R=301,NC,L]
```

But my postname always changes and this is why I'm  having problem wiht redirects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
# If the request is not for a valid file/directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]+)/[^/]+/?$ blog/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```